# Why is this python code printing one letter at a time?

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
def encrypt():
    msg = input("Enter the message you would like to encrypt: ").strip()
    print()
    key = int(input("Enter key to encrypt, a number 0-25: "))

    encryptedMessage = ""
    for ch in msg:
        if ord(ch) == 32: 
            encryptedMessage += ch 
            
        elif ord(ch) + key > 122:
            #after z moves back to a, a = 97, z = 122
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 122 
            encryptedMessage += chr(96+temp)
             
        elif (ord(ch) + key > 90) and (ord(ch) < 96):
            #moving back to a after z
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 90
            encryptedMessage += chr(64+temp)
                                          
        else:
            #incase of letters being both caps
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(ch) + key)
       
        print(encryptedMessage)

        main()
```

Sorry for the large amount of code I just really don't know whats making this happen. This is supposed to be a Caesar Cipher encryption program, you input the message and shift and it should print the code. However it only prints one letter and if I remove main() at the end it prints each letter at a time for example lets say the word was Lemons it goes, L, LE, LEM and so on. I would really appreciate if someone knew how to help with this issue, thank you!

Comment: Your `print` is inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just unindent `print(encryptedMessage)` so it's not in the loop.

```
def encrypt():
    ...
    for ch in msg:
        ...
    print(encryptedMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should suit you needs

```py
def encrypt():
    msg = input("Enter the message you would like to encrypt: ").strip()
    print()
    key = int(input("Enter key to encrypt, a number 0-25: "))

    encryptedMessage = ""
    for ch in msg:
        if ord(ch) == 32:
            encryptedMessage += ch

        elif ord(ch) + key > 122:
            #after z moves back to a, a = 97, z = 122
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 122
            encryptedMessage += chr(96+temp)

        elif (ord(ch) + key > 90) and (ord(ch) < 96):
            #moving back to a after z
            temp = (ord(ch) + key) - 90
            encryptedMessage += chr(64+temp)

        else:
            #incase of letters being both caps
            encryptedMessage += chr(ord(ch) + key)

    print(encryptedMessage)

encrypt()
```

Now if you see, it works perfectly

```hs
Enter the message you would like to encrypt: Hello World

Enter key to encrypt, a number 0-25: 15
Wtaad Ldgas

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: No problem, btw how do you decrypt it

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, just re-encrypt 25 more times to de-encrypt